# How can I find where my FB page have been shared?

Tags: social-media

How can I check where a page is shared on facebook? I'd like to check how many times it has been shared. How can I get this information?

Comment: Sorry but currently the question is too specific and unlikely to help others, as well as being unclear i.e failed to tell us what plugin, what cms, and if your using Facebook's api.

Comment: But it makes no difference. Assume you have any uri and you want to know where it has been shared on fb. The CMS, the plugins, the usage of the fb API makes no difference at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only direct answer is applicable facebook news feeds. If that's not a good enough answer, then contact Mark Zuckenburg. My apologies if I spelled his name wrong.

But really, the only way you'll know sharing info like this is to contact the people that run facebook.

As you know, anyone can choose to share a webpage on facebook, but because people have different facebook privacy settings, its very hard to find out where exactly content is shared since facebook privacy features are intended to keep unwanted guests outside of certain accounts. You can even see this for yourself when you browse a random person's profile with the highest level of security.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to see exactly where your page has been shared on Facebook, only how many times. For that you can use this site: http://sharetally.co/

Comment: That only appears to tell you the number of *times* a specific URL was shared.   It does not say anything about deep pages within the site, nor where the shares happen.

Comment: Exactly, because the latter is not possible.